# `switch`-like pattern matching control flow statement that matches any and all true cases?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, pattern-matching, programming-languages, control-flow

**NOTE**: this question is not asking for help solving FizzBuzz. Please don't post answers that just solve FizzBuzz. Answers to this question should relate to matching *multiple* true `switch` cases

Consider an attempted [FizzBuzz](https://imranontech.com/2007/01/24/using-fizzbuzz-to-find-developers-who-grok-coding/) solution in Swift using a [switch statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement):

```
func fizzBuzz(forInt int: Int) -> String {
    var output = ""
    switch 0 {
    case (int % 3): output += "Fizz"
    case (int % 5): output += "Buzz"
    default:
        output = String(int)
    }

    return output
}

// FAILS
assert(fizzBuzz(forInt: 15) == "FizzBuzz", "15 should output `FizzBuzz`, not `Fizz`!")
```

The correct output on iteration `15` should be `"FizzBuzz"` because 15 is divisible by both 3 and 5.

But the program above outputs `"Fizz"` because only the *first* passing `case` is executed.

The [Swift docs state](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html):

> A switch statement executes an appropriate block of code based on the **first pattern** that matches successfully.

It seems that it would be useful for there to be a similar, `switch`-like statement that matches **any true case** rather than just the first.

Pattern matching patterns can currently be used in the following situations:

> You use these patterns in a case label of a switch statement, a catch clause of a do statement, or in the case condition of an if, while, guard, or for-in statement.

Matching **multiple** patterns seems impossible in Swift. Options considered:

#### fallthrough

Switch `fallthrough` allows one executed case to fall into and execute the physically next case, but *without* actually testing the case statement. It does not allow multiple, arbitrary, unordered cases to be executed only if matching.

#### multiple `if` statements

Multiple `if` statements produce the desired behavior, but are annoying for the same reasons `switch` is often preferred over `if-else` blocks.

```
if (i % 3 == 0) {
    // ...
}
if (i % 5 == 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Namely re-stating the variable being tested in each case, no compiler protection that we're evaluating the same single variable against multiple cases, etc.

#### tuples, etc.

Yes, it's possible to do things like switch on a tuple to produce the correct output value. But that involves duplicating code inside the cases.

```
switch (i % 3, i % 5) {
case (0, 0):
    output += "FizzBuzz"
case (0, _):
    output += "Fizz"
case (_, 0):
    output += "Buzz"
```

The goal of this question is to have only 2 cases for "Fizz" and "Buzz". *Combined* execution of the true cases should produce "FizzBuzz", not a separate 3rd case that duplicates the strings.

### Related:

[Switch to match multiple cases from OptionSetType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358076/switch-to-match-multiple-cases-from-optionsettype)

### Question:

Does there exist a `switch`-like pattern matching control flow statement that matches any and all true cases? If not in Swift, do any languages contain such a feature?

Comment: Is this actually a conceptual question or do you want to solve this exact issue? This can be solved easily using a switch statement.

Comment: @DávidPásztor how so? I'm interested in execution of all matching cases in a switch statement. Yes, it's easy enough to get the correct output of "FizzBuzz" through other means :P

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975542/swift-2-expression-pattern-of-type-bool-cannot-match-values-of-type-int/33975661#33975661

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279000/switch-statement-in-swift

Comment: @LeoDabus both those links seem to be to successful implementations of FizzBuzz in Swift, but *not* anything to do with matching **multiple** `switch` cases.

Comment: If they were exactly duplicate of your question I would just close it. Considering that you have not posted any reference to them in your question I thought you might want to take a look at them.

Comment: Have you ever though about adding a case statement to that switch: `case (int % 15): output = "FizzBuzz"`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017533/is-there-a-way-to-test-an-optionset-with-a-switch-statement

Answer (score 0):

This loop-nested `switch` syntax executes each true case in order, not just the first true case.

```
for i in 1...100 {
    var output = ""

    for eachCase in 0...1 {
        switch (eachCase, 0) {
        case (0, i % 3): output += "Fizz"
        case (1, i % 5): output += "Buzz"
        default: break }
    }

    if output.isEmpty {
        output = String(i)
    }

    print(output)
}
```

I'll leave it to the reader to determine situations where this is better behavior than alternative such as multiple `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

There was a Swift evolution proposal to introduce a `continue` statement within Switch cases, which would resume pattern matching against the remaining cases.

> #### [swift-evolution] [Pitch] Introduce continue to switch statements
>
> This proposal completes the switch statement's control flow transfer suite by introducing `continue`. This change adds functionality that many developers expect (but do not get) from `fallthrough`.
>
> https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160704/023955.html
>
> https://gist.github.com/erica/04835de3d3d9121ef7308dd9b093158a
>
> Introducing `continue` means "resume pattern matching after executing this case clause". It offers more nuanced control than currently exists within switch.